# How do I provide proper fire protection in this situation?

Tags: insulation, hvac, fire-hazard

HVAC guys are running a vertical duct (supply and return) from my basement to my 2nd floor attic.  It will run adjacent to an exterior wall and will eventually be enclosed in a drywalled-in vertical soffit.  My question is in regards to the insulation in the exterior wall cavity:  Would the metal of the ducts touching the kraft-faced insulation be enough to provide the fire protection that kraft-faced insulation needs?

Or should I go with unfaced insulation and just use 6 mil poly as my vapor barrier?  Or maybe a combination of unfaced insulation and a foil faced foam board?

Comment: Can you simply cover it with fire-taped drywall? That would make me feel better than the other alternatives.

Comment: You should go ahead and type that up as a formal answer since that's what I ended up doing.  I didn't want to drywall behind it because I was already squeezing a 16" duct into a 16" spot, but I can make the extra 1/2" (from the drywall thickness) work so I might as well go with something I know for sure the inspector won't think twice about.

Comment: Thanks milkbone, done. I'm usually reluctant to enter quick comments as answers, but there really isn't much else to say this time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply cover it with fire-taped drywall. That would make me feel better than the other alternatives. It's really as cheap and easy as anything and will do the job without question.

Comment: On a related note, I ended up using 3/4" plywood as fireblocking above the 2" (pink) foam board above my interior basement/foundation walls.  Drywall is also typically used here but I'm not ready to drywall that area yet, so I went with 3/4" plywood because the city (Madison, WI) website says that 3/4" plywood meets code the same way drywall does.  I'll probably use drywall everywhere else down there, but in a pinch the plywood should be fine.